# Increase suppotred page size for Calendar API

Tags: microsoft-graph, microsoft

By default we use $top=100 for our Calendar API requests for events enumeration (with /events endpoint). We want to increase the parameter to $top=1000. We tried that but unfortunately we receive a lot HTTP 503 errors from Microsoft.

Is it expected behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message you are getting?

Comment: 503 error with the following error message: `{ ErrorCode: "UnknownError", ErrorMessage: "" }`